# spring boot admin page keeps on loading applications

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-boot-admin

My spring boot admin keeps on loading applications forever

[image]

I only can only see the following error in console.

[image]

We are running the container behind proxy and I have configured the required properties as below.

```
server:
  forward-headers-strategy: native
  tomcat:
    redirect-context-root: false
```

Comment: Im facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Which version of spring boot admin are you using? I too faced this issue with earlier versions of admin server (the app loader icon would keep spinning when no apps are found).
Try upgrading your admin server version.

Comment: The admin version is 2.3.0

Comment: same issue regardless the boot admin version, but it worked in the past